# EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/x-httpd-php") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection

Tags: php, html, eventsource

I'm trying to use EventSource and I'm using this code:

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Above code is given in this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) of w3school.
But I got this error: EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/x-httpd-php") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

Anyone know why? I copied everything from w3school. I can not find out what the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means PHP is sending the default mime type header first.

My first guess would be that you have some whitespace (or an invisible character, like a utf8 BOM) in your php script file before the opening `<?php`. (See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Or it might be that it is sending back an error message? I'd recommend using curl, from the commandline, to debug it. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49486869/841830)  Alternatively, using the web developer tools in your browser to poke in to exactly what is being sent back.