# What is the most optimal way to create an MDT/CAD system? (AJAX,SSE,WebSocket)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, websocket, server-sent-events

Hello to whoever may be reading,

I've been working a long time on a backend for a website that provides a realistic Mobile Data Terminal and Computer Aided Dispatch system for roleplaying purposes online.

I originally utilized AJAX calls on a setInterval that refreshes part of a page literally ever 100 ms ish and on the PHP side, it runs an SQL query.

As you can imagine, this has proven to be very slow and ends up even managing to mess with the sessions and logging people in as other people (Don't ask how... I don't know). I've read about WebSockets and SSE, but I need to really decide on a method and transfer the entire system over so my simple question would be...

What is the best way to optimize my system? And could I have an example or two in practice?

Thank you so very much for reading,

**Example of AJAX call**

*JQuery*

```
      if (obs) {
        obs = false;
      }

      $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "mdt.php", 
        data: {  },
        success: function(result) {
          $("#mdt").html(result);
        }
      });
    };

setInterval(function() { if (!obs) { if (!paused) { refreshmdt(); } } }, 750);
```

*mdt.php*

`````
session_start();
include("../config.php");
include("../backend.php");

$panicsql = getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM Units WHERE Status='PANIC'");

if ($panicsql->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<script>togglePanic('activate');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>togglePanic('deactivate');</script>";
}
?>
<!-- Terminal -->
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-mobile"> Terminal</i></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox" id="terminal">
                      <li>
                        <a href="bookoff.php"><button class="btn btn-block btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Book Off</button></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content" id="" style="height:74.3vh;min-height:70vh;max-height:74.3vh;overflow:auto;text-align:center;">

                    <?php include("Ajax/status.php"); ?>
                    <br />
                    <h4><b>Change Status:</b></h4>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                      <a onclick="javascript:changeStatus('AVAILABLE');" class="btn btn-sq-sm btn-success">
                        <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i><br/>
                        AVAILABLE
                      </a>
                      <a onclick="javascript:changeStatus('EN ROUTE');" class="btn btn-sq-sm btn-warning">
                        <i class="fa fa-taxi fa-2x"></i><br/>
                        EN ROUTE
                      </a>
                      <a onclick="javascript:changeStatus('ON SCENE');" class="btn btn-sq-sm btn-primary">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i><br/>
                        ON SCENE
                      </a>
                      <a onclick="javascript:changeStatus('PRISONER');" class="btn btn-sq-sm btn-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i><br/>
                        PRISONER
                      </a>
                      <a onclick="javascript:changeStatus('UNAVAILABLE');" class="btn btn-sq-sm btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i><br/>
                        UNAVAIL..
                      </a>
                      <a onclick="javascript:changeStatus('PANIC');startPanic();" class="btn btn-sq btn-block btn-danger">
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-1x"></i>
                        PANIC
                      </a>
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <p>
                      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pnc" class="btn btn-sq btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-database fa-5x"></i><br/>
                        PNC
                      </a>
                      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#report" class="btn btn-sq btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit fa-5x"></i><br/>
                        REPORT
                      </a>
                    </p>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Active Incident / Observations -->
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-comments-o"> Active Incident</i></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li id="obsorinc">

                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content" id="activeInc" style="height:74.3vh;min-height:70vh;max-height:74.3vh;overflow:auto;">

                    <?php include("Ajax/activeInc.php"); ?>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>````
`````

Comment: You could move the html bit out of mdt.php and just let mdt.php act as data server.

Comment: That would speed things up drastically and make the code more manageable.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code does not require many changes to move over to server-sent events.

On the front-end, what you have as your `success` handler, is what becomes the `message` event handler. (In the spirit of refactoring one step at a time, you can continue to push ready-made HTML.)

You drop the interval timer on the front-end, and instead that moves to the back-end.

(The consequences of this are that a socket is being kept open, and a PHP process is now constantly running, rather than starting up and shutting down each time you poll. This might affect scaling to large number of clients.)

What needs to change on the back-end is to wrap what you currently have in a loop something like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
$prev_d = null;
while(true){
  $d = ...
  if($d != $prev_d){
    echo "data:".$d."\n\n";
    @ob_flush();@flush();
    $prev_d = $d;
    }
  usleep(100000); //Poll every 0.1 seconds
  }
```

As a first step, you could set `$d` by calling your existing PHP script!

Even with just these easy changes your overall process is now much better. Yes, the SQL database is still being polled once every 100ms per active user, but you now only send data over the socket when something has actually changed.

The next step would be to put all the static HTML on the client-side, instead of inside the PHP script. And then the script just sends back the results of the SQL query. That is more efficient, so you'll have a little bit less server and bandwidth load. However the main advantage is it will make the system easier to understand and maintain. Also easier to port to other languages, or other types of client.

The main loop would become something like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
$prev_sql = null;
while(true){
  $panicsql = getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM Units WHERE Status='PANIC'");
  if($panicsql != $prev_sql){
    $d = json_encode($panicsql);
    echo "data:".$d."\n\n";
    @ob_flush();@flush();
    $prev_sql = $panicsql;
    }
  usleep(100000); //Poll every 0.1 seconds
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! That's amazing, I'm not at home currently but I'll try and implement what you've suggested soon and let you know :)

Comment: This appears not to be working...

**Client-Side:**
`var source = new EventSource('mdt.php');
    source.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log(e.data);
    };`

**Server Side:**
`header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

$prev_sql = null;
while(true){
    $panicsql = getConnection()->query("SELECT Status FROM Units WHERE Machine=2");
    if($panicsql != $prev_sql){
        $d = json_encode($panicsql);
        echo "data:".$d."\n\n";
        @ob_flush();@flush();
        $prev_sql = $panicsql;
    }
usleep(100000); //Poll every 0.1 seconds
}`

Comment: Correction on the above: It is working, the SQL Query isn't for some reason. But, even when it is working, it's taking a long time before it outputs anything.

Comment: You'll need to do some troubleshooting, e.g. using the network tools in the browser, or curl, logging in your php script. (E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49486869/841830) Consider posting a new question if you think it is distinct from this one. Note that the code in my question was just to give you the idea, not necessarily ready to run. (E.g. in the second one you'll need to have defined `getConnection()`)